# SQLite-Net Extension and FileModel

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net-extensions

I want make a class representing file/folder, which has one or none parent and can contain files/folders. Because My folder is special case of file. My model looks like this:

```
namespace WPP3.Base.DataModel
{
  public class DbFileModel
  {
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool isFile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(DbFileModel))]
    public string ParentID { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(null, null, CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<DbFileModel> Files { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne(null, null, CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public DbFileModel ParentFile { get; set; }
  }
}
```

But when I am trying to use this class, SQLite-NetExtension throws this exception: "DbFileModel.Files: OneToMany inverse relationship shouldn't be List or Array".

Can you advise how make that class using SQLiteNetExtensions?

Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On relationships to same class, you have to explicitly declare inverse relationships like this:

```
[OneToMany(inverseProperty: "ParentFile", CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
public List<DbFileModel> Files { get; set; }

[ManyToOne(inverseProperty: "Files", CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
public DbFileModel ParentFile { get; set; }
```

There's [a pending issue](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/issues/17/improve-discovery-of-inverse-relationship) that would improve the discovery of inverse relationships so in future releases this may be no longer necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for help and SQLiteNetExtensions it is very useful tool :-) ;-)